# Cloudcompare Cut at specific coordination by one reference cut (third part of question)

Tags: cad

according to these two previous question:

[Cloud compare Cut at specific coordination by one reference cut](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35512/cloudcompare-cut-at-specific-coordination-by-one-reference-cut)

and :

[Cloud-compare Cut at specific coordination by one reference cut (second part of question)](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35637/cloudcompare-cut-at-specific-coordination-by-one-reference-cut-second-part-of-q)

I have test compare one target stl file with two the same reference file which one of the has aligned with the main target fie and the second stl reference file was aligned with another target file already like this for compared  with aligned refrence:

[image]

and the target file compare result data with the same reference file only change is this reference file is aligned with another target file !:

[image]

by this cut coordination for both of them:

[image]

So the variance and mean average values has been changed,so this change in values  thins is because of cloud-compare is trying to change the reference stl coordination in aligning process.

so i asked here for sure and to know have i can have had one specific cut in reference and target stl file based of Constance coordination of reference which is means every cut in two new stl files must be based of the reference coordination and be Constance for every two stl aligned models?

also asked here:

https://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4541&p=20675#p20675

**update:**

I have one mistake in my cutting process which i have cut also some tiny part of the final cut by dimension by segment tool which made that difference in the results, so by repeating the above process i get the same results for both of those cut by the same target and two same reference stl file with different alignment like this:

[image]

so it means by the same coordination and same reference STL file it would cut new aligned two stl file in same coordination.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have one mistake in my cutting process which i have cut also some tiny part of the final cut by dimension by segment tool which made that difference in the results, so by repeating the above process i get the same results for both of those cut by the same target and two same reference stl file with different alignment like this:

enter image description here

[image]

so it means by the same coordination and same reference STL file it would cut new aligned two stl file in same coordination.